# Can not install Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh4HI.png)I was trying to use Anaconda to install Jupyter Notebook via command "conda install jupyter", but it was failure.

The error msg was like:

```
Preparing transaction: done

Verifying transaction: done

Executing transaction: done

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::icu-58.2-ha66f8fd_1'.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\yanqing\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pymc3\\Library\\bin\\icudt58.dll'
```

Comment: Do you have admin permissions to be able to install applications on the computer?

Comment: please answer @RHP question

Comment: @RHP  I run the application(shell) through admin mode, but still failure with that error.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you don't have permission to install any package at the system level.
You can install it at the user level with

`conda install jupyter --use-local`

Comment: I tried to use the command you suggest but still not success with the same result